# Alternative to xargs for processing pipeline

Tags: shell, unix, curl

I am trying to run a curl command which will need arguments coming in from a pipe

```
some operation | sort | head -n -2 | curl -s "blah/blah/<argument goes here>/blah"
```

i cant figure out how to pass each argument one at a time. One way that i found was

```
some operation | sort | head -n -2 | xargs -l "$" curl -s "blah/blah/$/blah"
```

but i get

```
xargs: $: No such file or directory
```

what does it mean? why is it trying to read $ as a file?

Comment: Not sure what were You trying to do. But Your first "$" is being interpreted as a command. And `-l` has been deprecated for some time. Basically, the answer would be --- because You just told to read $ as a file.

Comment: ---? where does it go

Comment: `-l` takes a number, so `$` doesn't make sense as argument to it anyhow.

Comment: ...anyhow, why would you be using this instead of `sort <somefile | head -n -2 | xargs echo`? Which is still a bit broken, by the way -- you'd want `xargs -d $'\n'` to avoid some nasty bugs around lines with spaces or quotes -- but less so. Also, `echo` itself has a lot of places where it's poorly defined; `xargs printf '%s\n'` would be a better alternative.

Comment: (`cat somefile` is wildly inefficient compared to `<somefile`, because it requires starting `/usr/bin/cat` and reading from a pipe, rather than handing `sort` a direct handle on `somefile`; such a direct seekable handle is particularly useful when sorting really big streams, because it means `sort` can split off into subprocesses, each reading and sorting from a different part of the file, and then merge their results together -- but `cat` can't provide such a thing, because a FIFO can only be read beginning to end).

Comment: well, echo is just an example. actually, i want to post a curl command for each argument that xargs receives

Comment: ...in general, though, when providing a command that's broken, it's helpful to describe what you *intend* it to do. After all, when reading it, we see the same thing that the OS itself does -- an invalid command; that doesn't tell us what was intended by its author.

Comment: okay, you want to do a POST with `curl` -- with what characteristics around parallelization and error handling? As many as possible at once? One at a time? Exiting at the first error, or continuing? ...?

Comment: ...it may well be that `xargs` isn't the right tool for the job to begin with. I'd probably use a BashFAQ #1 loop if you don't need parallelization -- see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: BTW, `-l` is a GNU extension -- it's not found in the POSIX specification for `xargs` -- so the generic unix tag (specifying a generic POSIX environment) isn't sufficient.

Comment: one at a time. parallelization is not needed

Comment: so, the tricky thing here is that I can easily enough write an answer about the best-practices way to iterate over lines emitted from a pipeline (such as `sort | head`) and run an arbitrary shell command (such as `curl`) for each -- but that wouldn't be responsive to your question as asked, and would be unfair to the person who wrote the existing answer.

Comment: i can modify the question

Comment: ...sure; the thing is, modifying the question in a way that makes prior answers invalid is frowned on because it wastes the work done by the people who answered the question in its prior state.

Comment: makes sense, i did not know that xargs is not the proper way of doing this and i thought that maybe something is wrong with my environment. otherwise i would have framed the question differently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the best-practices way to read a string line-by-line:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ - not /bin/sh, or <() will be a syntax error

while IFS= read -r line; do
  curl -s "blah/blah/$line/blah"
done < <(some operation | sort | head -n -2)
```

Comment: thanks, but i get -r command not found

Comment: Can you pastebin *exactly* what you typed (or the contents of your script), how you invoke that script, and its output? Preferably somewhere without ads, ie. gist.github.com or ix.io

Comment: ...if `-r` is being parsed as a command name, rather than as an argument to `read`, then the usage isn't a precise match for what I gave here.

Comment: please see the edit. i think the issue with r was improper spacing. i fixed that. now the $ is again being literally interpreted so my curl fails as it is an invalid parapmeter

Comment: @AbtPst, you notice that I used double-quotes, not single quotes? That's an important detail. If you want me to critique the correctness of the `curl` command line, I need to see the *actual* `curl` command line.

Comment: @AbtPst, ...also, note that I used `$line`, not `$` alone, to be replaced with the substituted contents. Please test that my answer works **exactly the way I gave it** before you go do something different and complain that that different thing didn't work.

Comment: @AbtPst, ...mind you, if what needs to follow the substituted *isn't* a `/`, then you may need to use `${line}`, not `$line`, to prevent extra characters to be treated as part of the variable. Once again, details matter, and if you hide the details of your work, we can't help find the problems in those details.

Comment: perfect, it works now. i had put $ instead of $line. so in this case, are $line and ${line} equivalent?

Comment: `${line}` and `$line` are equivalent except when you need to concatenate with a literal string that can be part of a name. For instance, `$line_foo` tries to find a variable named `line_foo`, whereas `${line}_foo` expands the variable named `line`, and puts `_foo` on the end of the result.

Comment: got it. i tried to put ${line} at the end as `curl -s "$CURL_URL/GET/${line}"` but now the argument gets passed in as `[xyz-*]` which is invalid. how can i correct this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110937/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-abtpst).

Comment: unfortunately, i cant access the chat feature from work. is there a quick fix for this? i really appreciate your help

Comment: First place to start is to compare the command line emitted by `bash -x yourscript` with the curl command line you'd write by hand for that same URL. Once you've done that, you have a better question -- albeit one that should be asked *as a separate question*, if it's not already in the knowledgebase.

Comment: i did `echo "curl -s \"$CURL_URL/GET/${line}\""` and i get `curl -s "http://hostName:port/GET/xyz123"` which is perfect. so, now why does this command not get executed? from the error i get, it looks like the command that is being executed is `curl -s "http://hostName:port/GET/[xyz123]"`. how is it possible?

Comment: Don't ever trust echo. Use `set -x` (inside the script) or `bash -x yourscript` (when invoking it), as I said.

Comment: ...in particular, `\"...\"` is wrong; that makes *literal* quotes, not *syntactic* quotes, which are the kind you need.

Comment: ...`echo` prints only literal quotes, which is part of why believing that what `echo` emits is equivalent to what the same command without `echo` on the front runs is so very wrong.

Comment: i did bash-x and i got `curl -s http://hostName:port/GET/xyz123 {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"No feature for name [xyz123]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"No feature for name [xyz123]"},"status":400}` so i cant understand whats going on.

Comment: If the `bash -x` doesn't show `[xyz123]` in the argument list, then that's not what is actually being run.